# hard to solve 2D integral

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, integral-transforms

I want to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int_\mathbb{R^2}\frac{\sin(ak)}{k}e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}}d^2k
$$
and my idea was to do a transformation into polar coordinates. with $d^2k=k\,d\phi\, dk$ I get
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(ak)e^{ikr\cos(\phi) }\,d\phi\, dk
$$
but then I don't know how to deal with this term. I know that if it was 3D, I could make a transformation into spherical coordinates and substitute $\cos(\phi)=z$ and it would work. but in 2d I can't do that because I don't get a $\sin(\phi)$ from the differential that I'd get from spherical coordinates.
My idea now is to still somehow make a transformation into spherical coordinates although it is 2D. Could I do that? or is there another way to solve this integral?

Comment: Did you show your integral converges in first place? I'm probably mistaken but that seems to be divergent.

Comment: What does $\frac{\sin(ak)}{k}$ mean for $k\in\mathbb{R}^2$? In one dimension, this is the inverse Fourier transform of the $\mathrm{sinc}$ function which is the Fourier transform of a characteristic function.

Comment: @davide Trono why do you think that its divergent ?

Comment: @nicolas $k=|\vec{k}|$

Comment: The $\phi$ integral is the Bessel function $J_0$, look at the [integral representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel's_integrals)

Comment: Okay. But only almost or not ? I mean the interval length is right but not the borders. and if you try $cos(\phi)=sin(\phi+\pi/2)$ or $ cos(\phi)=sin(\phi-3\pi/2)$ and then substitute $z=\phi+\pi/2$ or $z=\phi-3\pi/2$ in both cases you dont get the for $J_0$ much needed borders $\pi$ and $-\pi$.

Comment: help plssssssss

Comment: The integrand is $2\pi$ periodic, so any interval of length $2 \pi$ will do

Comment: okay thanks. got it now